# Given a graph and a subset of its vertices, how to get an induced subgraph by customizing?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

An **induced subgraph** of a graph is another graph, formed from a subset of the vertices of the graph and all of the edges (from the original graph) connecting pairs of vertices in that subset.
For example:

```
Graph[{"A" <-> "B", "A" <-> "C", "A" <-> "F", "B" <-> "D", 
  "B" <-> "E", "D" <-> "E", "A" <-> "E", "B" <-> "F"}, 
 VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

There is only one subgraph induced by {A, B, D, E} in the above graph:
[image]

The InduceSubgraph function does not seem to be directly available from Mathematica.

- https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/InduceSubgraph.html

When I use the Combinatorica package, it breaks mathematica's own Graph function.

[image]

So I wanted to get the induced subgraph by extracting sub-matrix. But I am  not very clear *how the vertex labels of the graph correspond to the labels  of its adjacency matrix*. So the code below is elementary and not very reliable.

```
Inducedgraph[g_, vlist_] := Module[{sub}, AdjacencyMatrix[g];
   sub = s[[vlist, vlist]];
   AdjacencyGraph[sub]];
```

Especially when vertices of a graph are labeled with letters rather than numbers, it seems more important to find reliable code.

**Edit:** Thanks *yode* for the reminder that `Subgraph` can do that. But I'm also interested in a custom implementation of this function.

Comment: Why don't you use code to represent your graph? Is it because you want the responser to construct?

Comment: [Subgraph](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subgraph.html) is your after?

Comment: @yode Thanks. We can get it straight away. I was under the illusion that subgraph functions can only input edges. I'll delete this simple question shortly.

Comment: @yode Or change the question to how to customize a function to get a induced subgraph.  The  implementation is also that I'm interested in, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g1 = Graph[{"A" <-> "B", "A" <-> "C", "A" <-> "F", "B" <-> "D", "B" <-> "E", "D" <-> "E", "A" <-> "E", "B" <-> "F"}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]  
vlist={"A", "B", "D", "E"}
```

Using the built in function:

```
Subgraph[g1, vlist]
```

[image]

Custom Function:
(Creates a graph from edges where both vertices are in the list)

```
InducedGraph[g_, v_] := Module[{},
  Graph[Select[EdgeList[g], 
    MemberQ[v, First[#]] && MemberQ[v, Last[#]] &], 
   VertexLabels -> Automatic]]
InducedGraph[g1, vlist]
```

[image]